# C++ AVL tree iterator will not increment properly

Tags: c++, iterator, infinite-loop, avl-tree

I have implemented a class iterator inside my AvlTree class. My AvlTree node is as follows:

```
    struct AvlNode
{
    Comparable element;
    list<int> lines; //line occurrences
    bool flag; //checks validity
    AvlNode   *left;
    AvlNode   *right;
    AvlNode   *parent; //parent pointer 
    int       height;

    AvlNode( const Comparable & theElement, AvlNode *lt, AvlNode *rt, AvlNode *pt,
                                                     int h = 0, bool b = true )
      : element( theElement ), left( lt ), right( rt ), parent( pt ), height( h ), flag( b ) { }
};
```

My iterator is as follows:

```
     class iterator
 {
    protected:

        friend class AvlTree<Comparable>;
        AvlNode * node;

        AvlNode * findInOrderSuccessor(AvlNode * & t)
        {
            AvlNode * temp;
            //node has a right child
            // so successor is leftmost node of right subtree
            if(t->right != NULL)
            {
                temp = t->right; //go right
                //go all the way left
                while(temp->left != NULL)
                {
                    temp = temp->left; 
                }
                return temp;
            }

            //node has no right child
            //if we are someone's left child, go up one
            if(t->parent->left == t)
            {
                //return your parent
                temp = t->parent;
                return temp;
            }
            //if we are someone's right child, go up until the current node
            //is someone's left child, then go up one more
            temp = t->parent;
            while(temp->parent->left != temp)
            {
                temp = temp->parent; //go up 
            }
            //return your parent
            temp = t->parent;
            return temp;

        }

    public:
        iterator(AvlNode * p) : node(p)
            { }

        //overload * to make *iterator return the element of its node
        Comparable & operator*() 
            { return node->element; }

        iterator operator++ (int) //postfix operator
        {
            node = findInOrderSuccessor(node);
            return iterator(node);
        }

        // == comparison overload
        bool operator==(iterator  rhs)
            { return node == rhs.node; }
        // != comparison overload
        bool operator!=(iterator  rhs)
            { return !(*this == rhs); }
};
```

My AvlTree also has a begin and end iterator as public members:

```
    //begin iterator points to leftmost node
iterator begin()
{ //return pointer to leftmost node
    AvlNode *temp = root;
    while(temp->left != NULL)
        temp = temp->left;
    return iterator(temp);
}

//end iterator points to one after rightmost node
iterator end()
{ //return NULL right pointer of rightmost node
    AvlNode * temp = root;
    while(temp->right != NULL)
        temp = temp->right;
    return iterator( temp->right );
}
```

My problem is that when I try to run the following in main:

```
    for(AvlTree<string>::iterator itr = tree.begin(); itr != (tree.end()); itr++)
        cout << *itr << endl;
```

Instead of outputting all the words in the string tree inorder, I get an infinite loop of the first in order item in the tree. I can't seem to figure out why it would not be moving past the first item.

Comment: Your `end` operator seems to be the same as `return iterator(NULL);`. I would suggest adding *lots* of trace output to your `findInOrderSuccessor` function and see where its behavior diverges from what it should be. (There's a good chance the problem is that the tree structure is corrupt, by the way. So log pointer values too and make sure a node isn't its own left node or something like that.)

Comment: can you please explain a little what you are doing at this line: `AvlNode * findInOrderSuccessor(AvlNode * & t)`? Why have you rewritten operator `*` and how are you using it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I already know that everything in my tree implementation is correct. The only problems I receive are with iterator.

Comment: @Matteo I want my iterator operator++ to function in such a way that, starting with an iterator equal to the begin iterator member of my tree, I can simply use the postfix incrementer to go through my tree in order. So `AvlNode * findInOrderSuccessor(AvlNode * & t)` is meant to take the AvlNode member of an iterator and find the in order successor of the node and return an iterator that points to it. Operator `*` is meant to dereference, so `*itr` gives `element` of the iterator `itr`'s node

Comment: @Netsuki `++` is clear to me, what I don't understand is why you have rewritten `*` operator, couldn't you simply use the standard operator of dereferentiation?
Because by rewriting it it becomes difficult (at least for me) to interpret what kind of argument you are passing to the function `findInOrderSuccessor(AvlNode * & t)`, which is in my opinion where you could have sum bugs...

Comment: @Matteo The operator `*` is only overloaded in respect to an iterator object. Say I have `iterator itr`, if I then said `*itr` it would return the `Comparable element` of node itr points to. The code `AvlNode * & t` is simply passing a reference to a AvlNode pointer, and has no bearing on the iterator operator `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following iteration code works (from [my AVL tree](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/structure/BAVL.h); substitute `left` and `right` for `link[0]` and `link[1]`):

```
BAVLNode * BAVL_GetFirst (const BAVL *o)
{
    if (!o->root) {
        return NULL;
    }

    BAVLNode *n = o->root;
    while (n->link[0]) {
        n = n->link[0];
    }

    return n;
}

BAVLNode * BAVL_GetNext (const BAVL *o, BAVLNode *n)
{
    if (n->link[1]) {
        n = n->link[1];
        while (n->link[0]) {
            n = n->link[0];
        }
    } else {
        while (n->parent && n == n->parent->link[1]) {
            n = n->parent;
        }
        n = n->parent;
    }

    return n;
}
```

As far as your code is concerned, first, `end()` does not need to find the rightmost node in order to return `iterator(NULL)`; it could just return that without looking at the tree.

The actual error in your algorithm however seems to be here:

```
        temp = t->parent;
WRONG:  while(temp->parent->left != temp)
        {
            temp = temp->parent; //go up 
        }
        //return your parent
WRONG:  temp = t->parent;
        return temp;

    }
```

The first line I flagged may attempt a NULL pointer dereference, and should be changed to:

```
while(temp->parent && temp->parent->left != temp)
```

And the second one to:

```
temp = temp->parent;
```

Also, you might have noticed from my code that the following is now superfulous; it can be removed, and will be handled exactly the same way by the (fixed) remaining code. It also suffers from the same NULL pointer dereference I pointed out just above.

```
//if we are someone's left child, go up one
if(t->parent->left == t)
{
    //return your parent
    temp = t->parent;
    return temp;
}
```